# Redux wait for multiple dispatches

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I have a data structure where events have a venue. I have separate actions that get the data, but in some instances I'll need both to properly render the component.

I don't think the `getEvents` action should also get the venue data, but I'm not sure if I should be grouping them at a container or component level, and what the best method of waiting for them both to complete is.

I'm just getting started with React and Redux, so any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Container:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { getEvents } from '../actions/getEvents';
import { getVenues } from '../actions/getVenues';
import Events from '../components/Events';

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    events: state.events,
    venues: state.venues
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    onGetEvents: () => dispatch(getEvents()),
    onGetVenues: () => dispatch(getVenues()),
  };
}

const EventsContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Events);

export default EventsContainer;
```

Component:

```
import React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Events extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.onGetEvents();
    this.props.onGetVenues();
  }

  render() {
    const events = [];

    for (let key in this.props.events.data) {
      events.push(this.props.events.data[key]);
    }

    return (
      <View>
        {events.map(event => { return <Text>{ event.name }, [get venue name]</Text>; })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You tagged this with `redux-thunk` so presumably you are using it? Can you post your actions? A thunk would be a good place to put this logic

Comment: can you share your repo for us to test?

Comment: @ken4z I wouldn't want to duplicate my `getVenues` database calls in `getEvents`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I eventually handled this, was to add a `loading` property to the action, then await that before rendering the component.

```
import React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default class Events extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.onGetEvents();
    this.props.onGetVenues();
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.events.loading || this.props.venues.loading) {
      return null;
    }

    const events = [];

    for (let key in this.props.events.data) {
      events.push(this.props.events.data[key]);
    }

    return (
      <View>
        {events.map(event => { return <Text>{ event.name }, [get venue name]</Text>; })}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```